# Did that person actually fail to save Menma?

Tags: anohana

## Spoilers below.

Did

> Poppo really fail to save Menma as she was drowning?

In real life, I doubt he would have just run away for help. It is known that her body washed away so if he saw her where she fell initially, it must have been just as she started drowning.

Is it known that he saw her, in the middle of drowning, and just left? Or did he see a body, or maybe just the flip-flop?

I need to know...

Answer (score 1):

It is revealed through flashbacks that Poppo was really quiet and shy when the accident happened. According to his flashbacks (assuming that they are accurate), he actually did see Menma drown; however, he could not do anything to help her because he was scared to do anything. This guilt is the main reasons why Poppo decided to travel the world and become more outgoing and extroverted.